# powershell pass $matches[0] to function

Tags: powershell

I have the following:

```
{
$matches[0]

$url = $matches[0]

$wc = new-object system.net.WebClient

$result = Invoke-WebRequest $url

$newresult = $result.Content -replace "`n",""

}

$olFolderInbox = 6
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)

$targetfolder = $inbox.Folders | where-object { $_.name -eq "Backup" }

$targetfolder.items | where-object { $_.body -match "\bhttps://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-    9+&@#/%=~_|$]" } | % {$matches[0]}
```

it searches the body's of an email in a folder for a url example emal body:

```
fred is good https://1.1.1.1:1111/fred.
```

the current script returns a list of matches fine for each matching body.

what I am trying to do is pass the % {$matches[0]} part to the function fred but its seem to only pass the last match and not all if I change it to:

```
$targetfolder.items | where-object { $_.body -match "\bhttps://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-    9+&@#/%=~_|$]" } | fred $matches[0]
```

Thanks?

Comment: Is `fred` written such that it can accept pipeline input?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each item, something like this should work though I can't test it from here at the moment:

```
$items = $targetfolder.items 

foreach($item in $items){
    where-object { 
    $item.body -match "\bhttps://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]" } |
    fred $matches[0]
}
```